# Store values return from query in text fields

Tags: jasper-reports

I created 3 text fields to store 3 values return from query (for example select ename from EMP ==> return 3 values :King, Allain and Joe ).

the 3 text fields contains the same value (King), I want to store value1 ==> text field1, ..., value3 ==> text field3. it's possible to do this using text fields?

Note : I created manually a table using text fields and static text.

Example :
[enter link description here](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/333697exp0.png)

Comment: Your question is unclear. You should post the sample with image

Answer (score 0):

Generally you do not want that kind of behavior. Most reports only require evaluation at row level i.e. if your datasource provided three values for `ename` then you only need one field to print them all. The field `ename` will simply acquire new value at each row so the values King, Allain and Joe will be printed as they they are fed to the field.

Comment: Thank you for your post. But the text field will acquire all the values if it's used into table, otherwise it contains the only one value.